# Ignore folders gitignore in repo

Tags: version-control, bitbucket

In my bitbucket repo I am trying to ignore all folders that contain _vti_cnf or even just the contents of these folders.

These folders are created throughout the system are are specific to each user and should not be in our repo.  They are not in just one directory, they are peppered throughout.

I have  tried :

```
_vti_cnf/
_vti_cnf/*
*_vti_cnf/*
```

And they keep wanting to be included in my repo. How can I ignore any folder that either begins with or contains this name no matter where it is in the repository.

Thanks for  your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude paths or files recursively by prefixing the pattern with `**/`, i.e. in your case via `**/_vti_cnf/`.

Comment: Thanks.  And that will ignore no matter where the folder is in the file structure?

Comment: Yes, it will ignore recursively.